# Max date record for items for given set of dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am looking for some help to create an efficient SQL query (SQL Server 2012) that will identify the latest records (date) for all the items in the table (table 2 below) on each of a list of given dates (table 1 below). Here are the tables and sample data set. The tables are rather huge (600 dates, 5K+ data entries each for 6000 items).

table 1: `qdate`:

```
QUERY_DATES
03/03/2015   
03/04/2015  
04/09/2015  
06/12/2015  
05/05/2016
```

table 2: `svalue`:

```
ITEM  DATA_ENTRY_DATE     VALUE 
1     03/02/2014          24  
1     03/02/2015          22  
1     04/04/2015          100  
1     03/09/2016          102  
2     03/02/2015          -25
```

Required SQL Result:

```
ITEM QUERY_DATES  VALUE   DATA_ENTRY_DATE  
1    03/03/2015    22     03/02/2015   
1    03/04/2015    22     03/02/2015   
1    04/09/2015   100     04/04/2015  
1    06/12/2015   100     04/04/2015  
1    05/05/2016   102     03/09/2016  
2    03/03/2015   -25     03/02/2015   
2    03/04/2015   -25     03/02/2015   
2    04/09/2015   -25     03/02/2015  
2    06/12/2015   -25     03/02/2015  
2    05/05/2016   -25     03/02/2016
```

Comment: Wasn't sure of your rule. Tried to clarify in an edit. Please revert if I erred.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT 
    i.item,
    q.query_dates,
    s.value,
    s.data_entry_date
FROM
    qdate AS q
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT DISTINCT item
      FROM svalue
    ) AS i
  OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT TOP (1) s.value, s.data_entry_date
      FROM svalue AS s
      WHERE s.item = i.item
        AND s.data_entry_date <= q.query_dates
      ORDER BY s.data_entry_date DESC
   ) AS s 
ORDER BY 
    item, 
    query_dates ;
```

Now about efficiency, I doubt there is way to make this blazing fast with a big table. Even with the rather small tables (600 dates, 6K items), you still want a result set of 3.6M rows.

An index on `(item, data_entry_date) INCLUDE (value)` will probably help a lot but still, it's 3 million rows of results. Are you going to display them? Or save them in another table for further analysis?

If there is another table with `items`, it would also be probably better to replace the `i` derived table with that table.

Comment: Agreed about the index.  And I don't see a great way for the system to scale.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't, I created a test-bed:

```
USE tempdb;

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.qdate') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.qdate;
CREATE TABLE dbo.qdate
(
    QueryDate DATETIME NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_qdate
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
);

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.svalue') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.svalue;
CREATE TABLE dbo.svalue
(
    Item INT NOT NULL
    , DataEntryDate DATETIME NOT NULL
    , DataEntryValue INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.qdate (QueryDate)
VALUES ('2015-03-03T00:00:00')
    , ('2015-03-04T00:00:00')
    , ('2015-04-09T00:00:00')
    , ('2015-06-12T00:00:00')
    , ('2016-05-05T00:00:00');

INSERT INTO dbo.svalue(Item, DataEntryDate, DataEntryValue)
VALUES (1, '2014-03-02T00:00:00', 24)
    , (1, '2015-03-02T00:00:00', 22)
    , (1, '2015-04-04T00:00:00', 100)
    , (1, '2016-03-09T00:00:00', 102)
    , (2, '2015-03-02T00:00:00', -25);
```

The following query returns the results you requested:

```
;WITH src AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT qd.QueryDate
        , sv.Item
    FROM dbo.svalue sv
        , dbo.qdate qd
)
, src2 AS
(
SELECT s.Item
    , s.QueryDate
    , sv.DataEntryValue
    , sv.DataEntryDate
    , rn1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.Item, s.QueryDate 
                          ORDER BY sv.DataEntryDate DESC)
FROM src s
    LEFT JOIN dbo.svalue sv ON s.Item = sv.Item
        AND s.QueryDate >= sv.DataEntryDate
)
SELECT *
FROM src2
WHERE src2.rn1 = 1
```

The first CTE, `src`, multiplies the query dates by the number of items.  As @ypercube said in his answer, this will very quickly get out of control as the quantity of both increase.

The second CTE uses the `ROW_NUMBER()` aggregate to partition by the item and querydate to allow the main query to only pull the most recent `svalue` row for each row in `qdate`.

---

Another method:

```
SELECT sv.Item
    , q.QueryDate
    , sv.DataEntryValue     
    , sv.DataEntryDate
FROM dbo.qdate q
OUTER APPLY (SELECT sv.*
            , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sv.item 
                                      ORDER BY sv.DataEntryDate DESC)
        FROM dbo.svalue sv
        WHERE sv.DataEntryDate <= q.QueryDate
    ) sv
WHERE sv.rn = 1
ORDER BY q.QueryDate;
```